# Delphi 10.4. Fast Report 6. REST application. Print Failure

Tags: rest, delphi, printing, fastreport

I have created a REST server in Delphi using WebBroker.  My intention is to use it as a label printer.  A client prepares and sends a JSON request detailing the printer name, Fast Report & variables.  The server reads the JSON, creates a tFrxReport object loads the requisite report and populates the variables.

This all works admirably, except it will not print to a physical printer.  If I select OneNote as my destination, the label is saved to the desktop.  If I select a network attached printer, no label emerges.

I have tried PrintOptions.ShowDialog:=True  The print dialog shows, indicating the correct printer, but it does not print.

If anyone has any experience, could you point me in the right direction please?

```
function processJson(itm : sat; jtr : tJsonTextReader): sat;
var
idx : integer;
//itm : sat; // simple array type [idx, 'val1', 'val2']
begin
setlength(itm,0);
idx:=0;
while jtr.Read do
  begin
  if jtr.TokenType = tJsonToken.PropertyName then
    begin
    setlength(itm, length(itm)+1);
    itm[idx].st_idx := idx;
    itm[idx].st_code := jtr.Value.ToString; // property name
    jtr.Read;
    itm[idx].st_desc := jtr.Value.AsString; // property value
    inc(idx);
    end;
  end;
processJson := itm;
end;

function getPrinterInfo(pnam: string):printinfo_type;
var
ptr : printinfo_type;
idx : integer;
begin
ptr.idx := -1; //default printer
ptr.name := trim(pnam);
for idx := 0 to Printer.Printers.Count - 1 do
  if AnsiContainsText(Printer.Printers[idx], ptr.name) then
    ptr.idx  := idx;
result := ptr;
end;

procedure Ttfdq.tfdqactLabelAction(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest;
          Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
post : simpleArray_type;
pdx, idx, iitm  : integer;
jtr  : tJsonTextReader;
sr   : tStringReader;
pish : string;
fr : tFrxReport;
thePtr : printinfo_type;
itm : sat;
tstprt : boolean;
begin
d.myHost   := 'http://' + Request.host + ':' + intToStr(Request.ServerPort);
d.hostIP   := Request.host;
d.Request  := Request;
d.Response := Response;
d.remAddr  := Request.RemoteAddr;
post       := explode(Request.Content);

tstprt := false;
pdx := isset(post, 'json');
pish:='';
if (pdx >=0) then
  begin
  sr :=  tStringReader.Create(post[pdx].st_desc);
  jtr  := tJsonTextReader.Create(sr);
  while jtr.read do
    begin
    if jtr.TokenType = tJsonToken.StartObject then
       itm := processJson(itm, jtr);
    end;


if fileexists(itm[2].st_desc) then
  begin
  thePtr := getPrinterInfo(itm[1].st_desc);

  fr := tFrxReport.Create(nil);
  fr.LoadFromFile(itm[2].st_desc);

  // pre load any vars so report does not fail
  for idx := 0 to fr.Variables.Count-1 do
    fr.Variables.Items[iitm].Value := frText('');

  for idx := 4 to High(itm) do
    begin
    pish := pish + 'index of '+itm[idx].st_code+' = '+ intToStr (fr.Variables.IndexOf(itm[idx].st_code))+'<br>';
    iitm := fr.Variables.IndexOf(itm[idx].st_code);
    if iitm > -1 then
      fr.Variables.Items[iitm].Value := frText(itm[idx].st_desc);
    end;

if fr.PrepareReport then
    begin
    //fr.ShowPreparedReport;
    fr.PrintOptions.Printer := thePtr.name;
    fr.PrintOptions.PrnOutFileName := 'Trace Label';
    fr.PrintOptions.ShowDialog := tstprt;
    fr.ShowProgress := tstprt;
    fr.Print;
    end;
  fr.Free;
  end;

  Response.Content := pish ;

  end
else
  begin
  Response.Content := '<html>' +
    '<head><title>Label List</title></head>' +
      '<body>This is only used by print serve clients</p>'+
    '</body>' +
    '</html>';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Show your code, especially around "If I select" so we see how it successfully creates a file for the OneNote variant, but fails to start the print on a physical device.

Comment: edited to show code

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
fr.PrintOptions.PrnOutFileName := 'Trace Label';
```

I erroneously thought that would add a description in the print queue.  What it actually did is send the report into limbo :)

Comment: And even then the OneNote was saved successfully?

Comment: @AmigoJack yes, whenever I created a print-to-file, I got an output.